# Flatten An array element wise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two Arrays which look like this:

```
array1: [["abc","def","ghi"],["jkl","mno","pqr"]],
array2: [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

I want to operate a Flattening operation which gives me result like this: `Flatten(array1,array2)`:

```
result: [["abc","def","ghi",1,2,3,4,5],["jkl","mno","pqr",6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Any suggestions on the same?

**Edit 1: Both the Arrays always have the same length.**

Comment: is `array1.length` same as `array2.length` always?

Comment: Yes, and sorry I missed to mention that.

Comment: ok, i posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` on one of them and `concat()` it with corresponding element of other array

**Note:** I am considering length of both the arrays will be equal

```js
const arr1 = [["abc","def","ghi"],["jkl","mno","pqr"]];
const arr2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];

const flattern = (a1, a2) => a1.map((x, i) => x.concat(a2[i]))
console.log(flattern(arr1, arr2))
```

If lengths of arrays are not same then you will have to first find the larger array and then map over it.

```js
const arr1 = [["abc","def","ghi"],["jkl","mno","pqr"], ['a','b','c']];
const arr2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];

const flattern = (a1, a2) =>{
  if(a1.length === a2.length){
    return a1.map((x, i) => x.concat(a2[i]))
  }
  else if(a1.length > a2.length){
    return a1.map((x, i) => x.concat(a2[i] || []))
  }
  else{
    return a2.map((x, i) => x.concat(a1[i] || []))
  }
} 
console.log(flattern(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the length of the array is same, you could use `map()` over one array and `concat` the other.

```js
const array1 = [["abc","def","ghi"],["jkl","mno","pqr"]];
const array2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];

let result = array1.map((a, i) => a.concat(array2[i]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[...].flat()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat